# Using react-Beautiful-dnd, how can you change draggable dimensions before the drag begins (onBeforeCapture)

Tags: react-beautiful-dnd

This is the code I've found to retrieve the correct draggable element and edit it's dimensions, during the onBeforeCapture() responder. Changing dimensions during this responder is in accordance with the documentation. This seems to work in only changing the dimensions, the other problems is that I am using the renderClone method, and so the draggable is just dragging with a huge offset that is not close to the correct mouse position. Also dnd is treating the drop placeholder as if the draggable is the original large size. Is there any way to correct for this mouse position, and placeholder dimensions? I've looked into adding mouseDown/mouseUp handlers on the inner element of the draggable but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
const cardSize = 140;
const draggableAttr = "data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id";
const getAttr = (key: string, value: string) => `[${key}=${value}]`; 
const draggableQuery = getAttr(draggableAttr, update.draggableId);
const draggable = document.querySelector(draggableQuery);
draggable.setAttribute("style", `width: ${cardSize}px; height: ${cardSize}px;`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed onBeforeCapture was triggering after onDragEnd (therefore resizing the draggable improperly), so I created some state to remember the last beforeCaptureResult and `return` if it is equivalent to the current result.

Comment: Did you succeed in changing dimensions of the draggable while dragging it? I am trying to achieve something like when you drag a song in spotify, but have not succeeded or found a way of doing it.